# Laravel Route group using or condition for middleware

Tags: routes, laravel-5, authorization, middleware

I am trying to create custom authorization and authentication in Laravel 5.2.

So in my routes file, first i check if user is authenticated or not, using **auth** **middleware**.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

});
```

I have 3 users role.

1.visitor

2.manager

3.admin

and for manager and admin i have two middleware.

**ManagerMiddleware** (manager) and **AminMiddleware** (admin)

For a specific function i want to give access to both **admin** and **manager**.

For this purpose , i used this code

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin','manager']], function () {
        Route::get('test','TestController@index')
    });
});
```

Of course it does not work. Second middleware check both **admin** and **manager** and it fails because an user only belongs to a specific role.

So i want to use **or** in  `['middleware' => ['admin','manager']]`

Is there any way to do it in Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call the admin middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
    Route::get('test','TestController@index')
  });
});
```

If the user if registered as an Admin process to next request, if not, call the
manager middleware :

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (isAdmin())
            return $next($request);
        //If not admin call to ManagerMiddleware
        return app(ManagerMiddleware::class)->handle($request, function ($request) use ($next) {
            if (isManager())
                return $next($request);
            //if neither admin nor manager reject request
            return redirect()->home();
        });
    }
}
```

Or checking it the other way around, first manager then admin so that you can still use the admin priviledge independently. I don't know if that solution is convenient, that's what I would do so far.